# tmux scrolls slowly, scroll-speed-num-lines-per-scroll doesn't seem to work

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to make tmux scrolls as fast as iTerm2,

```
%> tmux -V
tmux 2.3
%> cat ~/.tmux.conf
set-option -g mouse on
set -g @scroll-speed-num-lines-per-scroll 5
```

But my configuration does not seem to work, I can see the line numbers changes slowly, so this is definitely not working

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this work using a tmux plugin.

First, I installed [TPM](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm):

`git clone https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm ~/.tmux/plugins/tpm`

Then I configured `@scroll-speed-num-lines-per-scroll` and added [`tmux-better-mouse-mode`](https://github.com/NHDaly/tmux-better-mouse-mode) and TPM to my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g @scroll-speed-num-lines-per-scroll 1  # change to the speed you'd like

set -g @plugin 'nhdaly/tmux-better-mouse-mode'

run -b '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

After reloading my tmux conf, I ran `prefix+I` to install plugins, and the scrolling speed responded to the `@scroll-speed-num-lines-per-scroll` setting.

Comment: It's been a while, but I just had a problem that set -g @plugin 'nhdaly/tmux-better-mouse-mode' didn't seem to be having an effect on my scroll speed but `prefix, I` was what I was missing